# C++: Unable to modify a certain record in a file

Tags: c++, file-io, file-handling

I am trying to make a login form and I have put in an option to modify the e-mail ID of the user once he has logged in. For that I have written the following code.

```
char newmail[50];
                         cout<<"Enter New Email Id\n";
                         cin>>newmail;
                         fstream f2;
                         f2.open("db.txt" ,  ios::out |ios::ate| ios::binary);
                         strcpy(u.email,newmail);
                         f2.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
                         cout<<f2.tellp()<<endl;
                         f2.write((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
                         f2.close();
                         cout<<"Details edited sucessfully\n";
              break;
```

The problem with it is: I log in. Select the option for modifying email id. Enter the new one. No errors, details edited successfully. Then when I go to check the user list (wrote a code for that as well, perfectly working), all users are nullified, i.e. their data is null but space is still occupied and there is only one record with all data and yes the email id is modified.I cannot figure out why all data is being nullified when I have specifically set the pointer at the current record using `f2.seekp(-sizeof(u),ios::cur);`.
I have cross checked the position of the pointer and the cursor is at its place.
The whole code is this:-

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class user
{public:
    char username[50];
    char password[50];
    char email[50];


    int reg()
    {
        cout<<"REGISTRATION FORM\n";
        cout<<"Enter User name\n";
        cin>>username;
        cout<<"Enter Email\n";
        cin>>email;
        cout<<"Enter Password\n";
        cin>>password;
    }
    int putdata()
    {
        cout<<"Username   "<<username<<"         "<<"Email ID  "<<email<<endl;
    }

    char* retuser()
    {
       return username;
    }
    char* retpass()
    {

        return password;
    }
    char* retmail()
    {
        return email;
    }


};


int main()
{int a=sizeof(user);
    char ans;
    int ch;
    fstream f;
    user u;
    do
    {
        cout<<"MAIN MENU\n";
        cout<<"ENTER 1 FOR NEW REGISTRATION\n";
        cout<<"ENTER 2 TO LOGIN\n";
        cout<<"ENTER 3 FOR MEMBER LIST\n";
        cin>>ch;

        if(ch==1)
        {
           u.reg();
           f.open("db.txt", ios::app|ios::out|ios::binary);
            f.write((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
            f.close();
            cout<<"Registration successful\n";
        }
        if(ch==2)
        {
             char uname[50];
             char pass[50];
             int flag=0;
             cout<<"LOGIN\n";
             cout<<"Enter Username and Password\n";
             cin>>uname>>pass;
             f.open("db.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
             f.read((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
             while(f)
             {
                 if(strcmp(u.retuser(),uname)==0)
                 {
                     if(strcmp(u.retpass(),pass)==0)
                     {
                         flag=1;
                         cout<<"Login Successful\n";
                         cout<<"USERNAME : -"<<u.retuser()<<endl;
                         cout<<"EMAIL ID : -"<<u.retmail()<<endl;
                         int pos;
                         pos=f.tellg();
                         pos=pos-a;
                         int i;
                         cout<<"Press 1 to modify email id, 2 to exit\n";
                         cin>>i;
                         if(i==1)
                         {
                             char newmail[50];
                             cout<<"Enter New Email Id\n";
                             cin>>newmail;
                             fstream f2;
                             f2.open("db.txt" ,  ios::out |ios::ate| ios::binary);
                             strcpy(u.email,newmail);
                             f2.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
                             cout<<f2.tellp()<<endl;
                             f2.write((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
                             f2.close();
                             cout<<"Details edited sucessfully\n";
                             break;
                         }
                         else if(i==2)
                         {
                             exit(0);
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 f.read((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
             }
             f.close();
              if(flag==0)
            {
                cout<<"Wrong username or password\n";
            }
        }
        if(ch==3)
        {
            cout<<"MEMBER LIST\n";

            f.open("db.txt", ios::in | ios::binary );
            f.read((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
            while(f)
            {
                u.putdata();
                f.read((char*)&u, sizeof(u));
            }
            f.close();

        }

        cout<<"Enter y to go to main menu\n";
        cin>>ans;
    }while(ans=='y' || ans=='Y');
}
```

Comment: Isn't your f.open() call destroying the previous contents of the file? Also, the code is fragile: if the user enters an email address longer than 49 characters, the buffer will overflow and cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Please elaborate on the f.open() call thing. Also i am well aware of that 49 characters constraint. This is just a school project, nothing major!

Comment: Try this: `std::cout << -sizeof(user) << std::endl;`. You might be surprised. (Isn't your program very slow to update the email? Mine is.)

Comment: You are opening the same file two times. Try to open it once

Comment: `ios::out |ios::ate| ios::binary` discards the contents of the file. `ios::in | ios::out |ios::ate| ios::binary` doesn't.

Comment: @Bob__ I am using 2 different streams. If I would merge them all into one, the stream is gonna become highly overloaded.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou can you tell where to do that change. I did it on the part when i open the `db.txt` file in the f2 stream, did'nt work.

Comment: Guys i have an update. The code worked perfectly on TURBO C++. It does not with GCC. I think we are missing something else.

Comment: @molbdnilo i am surprised! Please suggest an alternative.

Comment: @Harshdeep `int offset = sizeof(u);` and using `-offset` should do it. (`sizeof` is unsigned; negating a small unsigned value gives a huge unsigned value.)

Comment: @molbdnilo that worked. Now i notice many things more. My pointer is not at all getting set right. Working on that.

Comment: i have updated the code now. Many improvements, i have also edited the question so everyone please go through that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to modify the file at the right position you should open the file (one time) for input and output. I'll show you only the part of the code managing the change of the mail address, even if you should improve your code and add some user input checking in many other parts.

```
    if(ch==2) // I'd prefer a switch() here
    {
        char uname[50];
        char pass[50];
        int flag=0;
        cout << "LOGIN\n";
        cout << "Enter Username and Password\n";
        cin >> uname >> pass;
        fstream f("db.txt", ios::in | ios::out| ios::binary);
        if ( f.bad() ) {
            cout << "Error, unable to open users database file.";
            exit(1);
        }
        // check the position BEFORE reading the user
        int pos = f.tellg();
        while( f.read((char*)&u, sizeof(user)) ) {
            if( strcmp(u.retuser(),uname) == 0  
                    &&  strcmp(u.retpass(),pass) == 0 ) {
                flag = 1;
                cout << "Login Successful\n";
                cout << "USERNAME : -"<<u.retuser()<<endl;
                cout << "EMAIL ID : -"<<u.retmail()<<endl;
                int i;
                cout << "Press 1 to modify email id, 2 to exit\n";
                cin >> i;
                if( i == 1 ) {
                    char newmail[50];
                    cout << "Enter New Email Id\n";
                    cin >> newmail;
                    strcpy(u.email,newmail);
                    f.seekp(pos,ios::beg);
                    f.write((char*)&u, sizeof(user));
                    cout << "Details edited sucessfully\n";
                    break;
                } else if ( i == 2 ) {
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            pos=f.tellg();
        }
        f.close();
        if ( flag == 0 ) {
            cout << "Wrong username or password\n";
        }
    }
```